# Obscure bug when connecting the library gradle

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I try to connect the library balancedpayments. To do this, I wrote:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.balancedpayments:balancedpayments:1.4'
}
```

then I click sync gradle and everything is normal is going.but after I try to run the Error output:

```
Warning:Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.2.1 is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
         In case of problem, please repackage it with jarjar to change the class packages
Warning:Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.2.1 is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
         In case of problem, please repackage it with jarjar to change the class packages
Warning:Dependency commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.1 is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
         In case of problem, please repackage it with jarjar to change the class packages
Warning:Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.2.1 is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
         In case of problem, please repackage it with jarjar to change the class packages
Warning:Dependency commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.1 is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
         In case of problem, please repackage it with jarjar to change the class packages
Warning:Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.2.1 is ignored for release as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
         In case of problem, please repackage it with jarjar to change the class packages
Warning:Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.2.1 is ignored for release as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
         In case of problem, please repackage it with jarjar to change the class packages
Warning:Dependency commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.1 is ignored for release as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
         In case of problem, please repackage it with jarjar to change the class packages
Warning:Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.2.1 is ignored for release as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
         In case of problem, please repackage it with jarjar to change the class packages
Warning:Dependency commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.1 is ignored for release as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
         In case of problem, please repackage it with jarjar to change the class packages
:app:preBuild
:app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72102Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42102Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugJava
Note: D:\skip\Customer\app\src\main\java\com\skip\client\customer\ScanActivity.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
:app:preDexDebug
:app:dexDebug
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
    D:\AndroidSDK\build-tools\21.0.2\dx.bat --dex --no-optimize --output D:\skip\Customer\app\build\intermediates\dex\debug --input-list=D:\skip\Customer\app\build\intermediates\tmp\dex\debug\inputList.txt
Error Code:
    2
Output:
    UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
    com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lorg/apache/commons/codec/Decoder;
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:454)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:302)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:245)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:214)
        at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 36.197 secs
Information:1 error
Information:10 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

I can not understand what the problem is. please help.

Comment: In general two different libraries are defining the class org.apache.commons.codec.Decoder. It could be because multiple libraries are packaging this file, which they shouldn't do because it's a third-party library and should be included separately. If you're including this library on your own by including its jar file in your project, that exacerbates the problem. If you include it via its Maven coordinates instead of pulling in a bare jar, the build system will be better able to disambiguate it. There are many other SO questions on this error -- do some research to see how to solve it.

Comment: This is your answer, obviously http://stackoverflow.com/a/28025725/4369465