# Incomprehensible error starting the project (gradle)

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I connected a library `compile 'com.balancedpayments:balancedpayments:1.4'` 
when going Projects no errors. but when I try to run I see the error:

```
Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
WARNING: Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.2.1 is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
         In case of problem, please repackage it with jarjar to change the class packages
WARNING: Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.2.1 is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
         In case of problem, please repackage it with jarjar to change the class packages
WARNING: Dependency commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.1 is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
         In case of problem, please repackage it with jarjar to change the class packages
WARNING: Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.2.1 is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
         In case of problem, please repackage it with jarjar to change the class packages
WARNING: Dependency commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.1 is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
         In case of problem, please repackage it with jarjar to change the class packages
WARNING: Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.2.1 is ignored for release as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
         In case of problem, please repackage it with jarjar to change the class packages
WARNING: Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.2.1 is ignored for release as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
         In case of problem, please repackage it with jarjar to change the class packages
WARNING: Dependency commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.1 is ignored for release as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
         In case of problem, please repackage it with jarjar to change the class packages
WARNING: Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.2.1 is ignored for release as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
         In case of problem, please repackage it with jarjar to change the class packages
WARNING: Dependency commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.1 is ignored for release as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
         In case of problem, please repackage it with jarjar to change the class packages
:app:preBuild
:app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72102Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42102Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugJava UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDexDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:dexDebug
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lorg/apache/commons/codec/Decoder;
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:454)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:302)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:245)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:214)
    at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)


 FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
    D:\AndroidSDK\build-tools\21.0.2\dx.bat --dex --no-optimize --output D:\skip\Customer\app\build\intermediates\dex\debug --input-list=D:\skip\Customer\app\build\intermediates\tmp\dex\debug\inputList.txt
Error Code:
    2
Output:

    UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
    com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lorg/apache/commons/codec/Decoder;
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:454)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:302)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:245)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:214)
        at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 6.611 secs
```

I read an article (in Russian), which says that it is because of a conflict of libraries [enter link description here](http://weel.pro/base/notes/oshibka-execution-failed-for-task-appdexdebug-v-android-studio)

to fix the problem I'm trying to

```
configurations {
    all*.exclude module: 'httpclient'
    all*.exclude module: 'commons-logging'
}
```

Library exclude I got, but the error is not lost

Answer (score 2):

In order to investigate your problem, I created an empty project and added your dependency

```
compile 'com.balancedpayments:balancedpayments:1.4'
```

to app/gradle.build.

Got your errors. So what I did to finally build and run the project without errors:

In the same gradle.build add the following:

```
packagingOptions{
     exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
     exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
}
```

missing this entry will lead later to

```
Duplicate files written in ...
```

your `exlude` in `dependencies` won't help, so clean them.

and finally add

```
configurations {
   all*.exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
   all*.exclude group: 'org.apache.commons'
}
```

Synk gradle and hit Run to check if I'm right.

Notice that `org.apache` transitive dependency could be added to base dependency for some reasons, such as incompatibility with Android stock org.apache components. So it's up to you to check if `com.balancedpayments` will work.

Comment: what do you mean by "Notice that org.apache transitive dependency could be added to base dependency for some reasons, such as incompatibility with Android stock org.apache components."

Comment: Okay, let me explain these words. There should be some serious reasons why org.apache.* code could be added as a dependency, with such a fact in mind that HTTPCOMPONENTS are already present in Android system, so at first glance no dependency is needed. One of such reasons is that org.apache.* code in Android OS may be kinda old and thus incompatible with library's new features requiring new releases of apache http libs.

Comment: Tor_Gash, What do you in the case where the latest version of HTTPCOMPONENTS is used by a dependency, and you need that new version, instead of the old version provided by Android?

Comment: Please ask the topic library's developers why they do that, I didn't even read a line of that code. But I just guess that if a simple "import" were pretty well enough, no dependency would be needed